# Handle JS calculated CSS values without using inline or embedded styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If I would be able to use inline/embedded styles, I would do something like this:

```
variable.css('width', dynamicallyCalculated + '%');
```

But I can't use inline/embedded styles in my application.

Is there some simple way to achieve something like this, perhaps?

I don't mind to use jQuery and/or modern methods as long as it supported by modern browsers.

Comment: Why can't you use inline styles?

Comment: What can you do? Can you load additional stylesheets?

Comment: @HermanL lots of reasons. The point is - I can't. I need to find a workaround this

Comment: @mipi - You need to back that up. If you can't use inline styles for things like dynamically-calculated widths, you're working under a very odd set of restrictions. We can't guess what other restrictions are in place. Please provide a detailed explanation of those restrictions.

Comment: @Luca Yes, external. I just can't use inline/embedded styles and scripts, but everything external is free to go

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's not odd. Content Security Policy ring a bell?

Comment: Oh comeon... now you're downvoting it? Are you for real

Comment: And it was impossible to say in the question that you needed to support the CSP? Or if not, at least in response to Herman's question? Why keep people guessing when you're *asking them for help*? Moving on, but look at using classes. And yes, it'll be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can add stylesheets to your document using jQuery, by appending a `link` element to the `head` element and then adding the appropriate attributes once the element is added to the `head` (this ensures compatibility with some older IE versions):

```js
function addStylsheet(href) {
  $css = $("<link>");
  $("head").append($css);
  
  $css.attr({
    "rel": "stylesheet",
    "href": href,
    "type": "text/css"
  });
}
```

You'd use the function like this:

```
addStylesheet("/some/url/to/a/style.css");
```

The links have to be part of your CSP of course, so say it looks something like this:

```
Content-Security-Policy: style-src 'self'
```

Now you can only load in scripts that come from the same schema and domain and are loaded over the same port.

Comment: Thanks Luca, but it won't work as it should. The calculations are made several times in a second... Even if you'll do this for an interval of a second it will kill the heck out of it. But thanks for trying to help ;-)